# Android pattern to make code inside activities more readable

Tags: android, android-activity, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvp

I read about MVP patterns. When we are starting developing android applications we are almost by default using MVC (we usually have our models in "models" package, views are inside "res" folder and activities are basically controllers.

I have realized that some activities inside my applications are not very readable, they are easy to understand but it take some read it because of the amount of code (for example,set up listeners for seekBars, handling sending data do AlertDialogs,receiving data from AlertDialog, validation of data before sending to server.

I don't see any benefit of starting using presenter (in MVP pattern). Presenter holds reference to activity, and when I want to do something with my view(change some EditText for example), I will call some method on presenter that points back to some method in my view(activity).(Explained [here](http://thefinestartist.com/android/mvp-pattern))  All interactions with views are still handled inside activities which makes it hard to read.

Currently I implemented presenter layer just like some facade layer above activity. For example, there are methods like `BindModelToUiViews()` that have lot of code for setting up initial views(controls) on screen. **What is best practise to make android activities "clean" and more readable(maintanable)?**

Comment: Google recently introduced a [Data Binding Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html). It's a beta release but it could be an interesting starting point. Another (stable) option is [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

Comment: Android develoment does not imply MVC per se -- it suggests very thick controllers that are pretty much a God Object anti-pattern hidden behind activities. Another thing you are wrong about is that an XML layout is a view. No, it's not. It's just a way of how you declare it. Any activity, fragment or a view is typically a view from the MVP perspective.

Comment: One advantage of MVP is that you can separate domain logic (M), end-user representation (V) and the mediator between them (P) fully apart. Also, it allows you to write platform-independent presenters (and maybe models) that can be easily tested using view mocks in a regular JDK environment, and you can implement views for other platforms like JavaFX, GWT, even CLI. I find having interfaces, in the way they are bound, much easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I know teory about MVP. But I don't think it solves my problem oh having to much ui code inside view (activity) I know that code belongs here, but I'm trying to find a way to refactoring. MVP helps solve some other problems but not this.

Comment: @Vlado I see now. I was confused for _I don't see any benefit of starting using presenter (in MVP pattern)_. If you're going to remove some Android boilerplate, then probably thetonrifles's answer may fit your needs better.